# Error using svg package related to "clean" function

Tags: svg, dvisvgm

I am using the package svg to upload images. I have installed the package, and when I compiled the .tex file an error is been displayed saying
"Unknown option `clean' for package` svg'. \FamilyProcessOptions{SVG}"
Looking into the svg.sty file, there is a function "called" clean, and it is stayed as true:

\svg@dummy@key[true]{clean}

I have tried to change it to "false", but the error still appears.
Also downloaded an old version of the SVG package, but the error still appears.
Lastly, there is another error below the first one that says

"File `transparent.sty' not found. \usepackage"

I also installed the transparent package, but the first error of "clean" function was not solved

Any suggestion, or have someone also experienced this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The handling of package options by `svg` is flawed in this case, you should actually get a warning reading

```
The option key `clean' can only be used with package `svg-extract'
```

The question is, what you thought this option would do? It is not documented for package `svg` but only for `svg-extract`. So if your intention was to use package `svg-extract` then

```
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[clean]{svg-extract}
```

or

```
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{svg-extract}
\svgsetup{clean}
```

would both be valid usages, the latter one recommended as this would issue the meant warning if package `svg-extract` was not loaded.